# Can the Incompleteness Theorems be proven in the context of other logics, for example with Paraconsistent Logic?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

And, if they cannot be proven, does anyone take this as a good argument to adopt the alternate logic?

Comment: See [Paraconsistent Logic : Arithmetic and Gödel’s Theorem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-paraconsistent/#AritGodeTheo).

Comment: And see [Inconsistent Arithmetic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-inconsistent/#FouMat).